# Can't add UIBarButtonItem to toolbar

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

After going through every single stackoverflow solution for this problem, it's still frustratingly not working for me.

```
//UIBarButtonItem declaration
UIBarButtonItem* button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Text" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(myAction)];

//method 1
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: button1, nil] animated:YES];

//method 2
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:button1]];

//method 3
self.navigationController.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:button1];

//displaying toolbar
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

None of the above methods work for displaying a button on the toolbar - all I get is a blank toolbar. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Is `self.navigationController.toolbar` null or not ?

Comment: not null, Log Result: <UIToolbar: 0x81e23e0; frame = (0 460; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x81e24a0>>

Comment: for some reason I can add buttons to a separate instance of UIToolBar which I add as a subview, but I can't modify the built-in toolbar of uinavigationcontroller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move

```
//UIBarButtonItem declaration
UIBarButtonItem* button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Text" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(myAction)];

//method 1
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: button1, nil] animated:YES];

//displaying toolbar
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

to `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` this is the point where UINavigationController get toolbar items of UIViewController that it manages.

Comment: for some reason I can add buttons to a separate instance of UIToolBar which I add as a subview, but I can't modify the built-in toolbar of uinavigationcontroller.

Comment: OMG I'm so stupid. I knew I was doing something dumb wrong. At the bottom of my code, I had accidentally overwritten the method - (void)setToolbarItems:(NSArray *)toolbarItems animated:(BOOL)animated {
    
}, and left it blank, so anything I put above was not doing anything!

Answer (score 3):

use

```
self.toolbarItems=[NSArray arrayWithObject:button1]
```

Comment: theoretically it should be the same as the setToolbarItems method

Comment: you are adding toolbar items to navigationController.toolbarItems but I have used self.toolbarItems to add items.The other part of your code is fine.Only set items to self.toolBarItems (the viewController's toolbar) then the toolBarItems will be visible,not to its navigationController's toolBarItems.

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 3 / iOS 10, in the simplest case where your navigation controller will contain only one view controller, you may use the code below in order to display your view controller with a toolbar that contains a bar button item:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Show navigation controller’s built-in toolbar
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)

        // Set the view controller toolbar items
        let items = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button Text", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)]
        setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)
    }

}
```

---

However,  if you plan to have several view controllers in your navigation controller's stack, you will have to call `UINavigationController`'s `setToolbarHidden(_:animated:)` method in `viewWillAppear()` and `viewWillDisappear()` in order to properly show or hide the navigation controller’s built-in toolbar:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view controller toolbar items
        let items = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button Text", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)]
        setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Show navigation controller’s built-in toolbar
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Hide navigation controller’s built-in toolbar
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

}
```

Comment: setToolbarItems!! This is the function to call.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a **Swift** version, try this:

```swift
let someVC: UIViewController = ...
let someButton: UIBarButtonItem = ...
someVC.setToolbarItems([someButton], animated: true)
```

The `UINavigationController.toolbar` property documentation explicitly clarifies which API should be used for *setting* toolbar items:

> Management of this toolbar’s contents is done through the **custom view controllers** associated with this **navigation controller**. For each view controller on the navigation stack, you can assign a custom set of toolbar items using the `setToolbarItems:animated:` method of `UIViewController`.

-- [UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/toolbar)